# Is it impossible to add certain NBT tags to commands in PE?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've read a post that said that you can only add the CanDestroy and CanPlaceOn tag, is that actually true or is there a way to do other things, like getting unbreakable items?
Edit: This is not a duplicate. I've read the post and I just want to know what exactly it meant.

Comment: Oh come on, it's almost the same title even! Please do at least some basic research before asking a question. I also recommend reading the [tour].

Comment: That is literally the post I was referring to, I'm just not sure if it's impossible

Comment: If that post doesn't help you, you need to specify why not and what your actual question is.